# Jquery not changing input value

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using an ajax upload script (http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php) to upload a pdf and an image within a form. The pdf one works great and the hidden form field is manipulated with returned data ( an integer!). The image one receives the returned data but doesn't update the hidden form field

EDIT: I don't know how the extra paranthesis appeared when I copied and pasted - re pasted !

Here's my code

```
<div id="fileuploader">Image Upload</div><br/><div id="fileuploader2">PDF Upload</div></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="image" value="" id="image_id"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="pdf" value="" id="pdf_id"/>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($)
        {
            $("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
            url:"http://snug/worshipbanners/wp-admin/admin.php?page=worship-banners/index.php&amp;banners-upload=true&amp;filename=image",
            fileName:"image",
            allowedTypes:'png,jpg,gif',
            dragDropStr: "<span><strong>Drag & Drop 2050mm x 300mm CYMK PDF</strong></span>",
            returnType:'json',
            onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr){ $("#image_id").val(JSON.parse(data));console.log(data)}
            });


            $("#fileuploader2").uploadFile({
            url:"http://snug/worshipbanners/wp-admin/admin.php?page=worship-banners/index.php&amp;banners-upload=true&amp;filename=pdf",
            fileName:"pdf",
            allowedTypes:'pdf',
            dragDropStr: "<span><strong>Drag & Drop 2050mm x 300mm CYMK PDF</strong></span>",
            onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr){ $("#pdf_id").val(JSON.parse(data));console.log(JSON.parse(data))}
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: You did notice the extra parenthesis `()$("#image_id")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the returned type is JSON as it seems to be as you do `JSON.parse(data)`

You should add

```
returnType:'json', 


$("#fileuploader2").uploadFile({
            url:"http://snug/worshipbanners/wp-admin/admin.php?page=worship-banners/index.php&amp;banners-upload=true&amp;filename=pdf",
            fileName:"pdf",
            allowedTypes:'pdf',
            dragDropStr: "<span><strong>Drag & Drop 2050mm x 300mm CYMK PDF</strong></span>",
            returnType:'json', //ADDED HERE
            onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr){ $("#pdf_id").val(JSON.parse(data));console.log(JSON.parse(data))}
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I see an extra set of parentheses on one of the lines where you set the value of a form field. I wonder if that line is running at all. Try deleting the parentheses at the start of this line:

```
()$("#image_id").val...
```